# How to extract the URL from a web server in C

Tags: c, http, post, server

I'm making a simple Web Server in C, I want to extract the URL from a Post request, I've checked that I can extract some info using curl but I need the whole current URL, something like "Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" whit C#, but in C programming.

Comment: Do you know how POST request looks like? You will have to parse it to extract the data from several headers and combine them together.

Comment: There are no standard C libraries for http, so it all depends on which library you are using. You mention "curl", but you don't say whether you mean the utility or the library. If the latter, then you need to specifically ask about libcurl, not C.

Comment: `using curl` curl is written in C